# Access Global.asa.cs variables in controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to load my MVC 3 application settings into memory for better performance.

So far I can assign them in the global.asa.cs but I cannot access the variables in any controller. Any idea why?

**Global.asa.cs Code**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static string DBUserName = Properties.Settings.Default.DBUserName;
    public static string DBPassword = Properties.Settings.Default.DBPassword;
```

**HomeController code:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            _Authenticate(DBUserName , DBPassword );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access them by specifying the class name in which they are declared:

```
_Authenticate(MvcApplication.DBUserName, MvcApplication.DBPassword);
```

`MvcApplication` is the name of the class in this the two [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) are declared.

For this to work you need to declare the 2 fields as static:

```
public static string DBUserName = Properties.Settings.Default.DBUserName;
public static string DBPassword = Properties.Settings.Default.DBPassword;
```

Comment: I get the following error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to declare those fields as static. I will update my answer.